# Fills a form in another website and it show in one website

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, express

I am making a website where user can login. After login user can see different link of Complaint form of government website or any other website. If a user want to complaint he will be redirected to that page after clicking that link but I want to take copy of what users fill in that website So that I can show the user where he has filled a complaint form. How to do that I can retrieve data that a users fill in another website.

Comment: You have to scrap the data in real time.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the form on another website was a user's bank account login form. This would be highly problematic. Browsers do not provide this functionality because it would be insecure. If you could do it for your use case, someone else could do it for the purpose of stealing sensitive information.

However, you could write a browser extension, in which case the extension can request permission from the user to view their page data and send that data to your servers...

Comment: Suppose like a user have to complaint against a bank then he has gone to bank contact page by clicking link. I just want to know that user filled their form so I can show them in user profile page that he has filled that bank's form.

Comment: @ShivKumar then have them click a checkbox "I have filled out form XY.16 (b)" or input the information themselves, and let them click "save"  (on your site.) There is no general way to do what you want for just any arbitrary website.